# Create a table in dynamodb with read and write capacity unit to be provisioned with auto scaling in Python

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am trying to create a dynamodb table with  python and below is my code but how to keep ProvisionedThroughput readcapacity and writecapacity with auto scaling

```
 table = dynamodb_client.create_table(
    TableName=table_name,
    KeySchema=[
        {
            'AttributeName': 'DeviceID',
            'KeyType': 'HASH'  #Partition key
        },
        {
            'AttributeName': 'Timestamp',
            'KeyType': 'RANGE'  #Sort key
        }
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions=[
        {
            'AttributeName': 'DeviceID',
            'AttributeType': 'S'
        },
        {
            'AttributeName': 'Timestamp',
            'AttributeType': 'N'
        },

    ],

    )
```

Comment: How did it go? Still not sure that you should be using `ApplicationAutoScaling`?

Comment: Yes, unsure about using ApplicationAutoScaling.

Answer (score 1):

You have to setup [ApplicationAutoScaling](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/application-autoscaling.html), as autoscaling in DynamoDB is managed by Application AutoScaling. This is done using entire different set of boto3 commands, e.g. [put_scaling_policy](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/application-autoscaling.html#ApplicationAutoScaling.Client.put_scaling_policy).